# Possibility of creating a gun that can permanently paralyze a person?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons

I'm wondering whether it's possible to create a gun that shoots some kind of shock wave to permanently damage nerve cells and instantly immobilize a hostile target but leave them alive. Would such a weapon be feasible?

Comment: A bullet in the spine can achieve a permanent paralysis. Is that what you are seeking?

Comment: A normal gun is quite good at rendering a target immobile forever. They'd be dead but otherwise immobile. Not sure what leaving a hostile target alive but permanently immobile would help with.

Comment: @VLAZ Same reasoning behind full jacketed bullets in 20th century wars -- kill a man, put one out of action.  Drill a neat hole through him, you put three or four out of action -- the man shot, the corpsman tending him,and two stretcher bearers to carry him to the field hospital.

Comment: *permanently* is a problem word here.  Incapacitating someone for a short period without permanent (i.e. life long) paralysis is essentially what a taser does.  Likewise CS spray and similar will subdue a person, or many sedative drugs administered in various ways.  If you're sadistic enough to want to paralyze them for life while they're temporarily down, there are ways and you can be as "elaborate" as you like, but all risk killing someone AFAIK.

Comment: Whether or not it's *feasible*, this sounds a lot like the [Neural Disruptors](https://honorverse.fandom.com/wiki/Neural_disruptor) from Weber's Honorverse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't such a (known) effect in the real world -- lots of ways to *temporarily* stun or paralyze a person, but none of them are reliably permanent.

Permanent paralysis generally comes from severing the spinal nerves, or destroying critical parts of the brain's motor centers.  It *might* be possible to build a critical homing projectile (like a tiny cruise missile, really, since it has to find the correct location on the target's head from any firing angle) to strike the subject's head and administer a large magnetic pulse, which would induce a current in the brain tissue beneath the point of contact (as with Transcranial Magnetic Stimulation, only with the power dial turned way, way up) to destroy motor pathways.

While reasonably permanent, this wouldn't be reliable in its effects due to brain-to-brain variations -- some people might die almost immediately due to respiratory failure, others might only suffer loss of fine finger control, ability to tap dance, or ability to roll their tongue -- while still others with very atypical brain layout (possibly due to early childhood trauma?) might show no immediately visible effect at all.

A much more reliable method, though still with a fairly large probability of unintended target death, would be a similar homing projectile that seeks the C2-C3 spinal joint and deploys a blade to sever the spinal cord; this will result in complete quadriplegia, but *usually* won't stop breathing and digestive functions.

Answer (score 6):

Animals with lungs don't cope well with paralysis. Spiders and wasps and various kinds of parsitoid target things like arthropods because they don't have lungs, and even after total paralysis oxygen will continue to diffuse into their bodies and metabolic waste products will diffuse out (to a certain extent). There are long-acting neurotoxins that work well on a whole range of vertebrates, but they also stop breathing and so are rapidly fatal for those afflicted.

A solution, perhaps, is a gun that shoots a sticky web with high tensile strength filaments that entagles a victim and then hardens rapidly. They're not technically paralysed, but they're not going anywhere until someone cuts them out. Against the spirit of the question perhaps, but it avoids a bunch of ways of killing the target by accident, and doesn't require precision ballistic surgery.

Comment: I know the heart has a basic rythm even when paralized. The lungs also are on automatic but I'm not sure if it functions without a connection to the brain.

Comment: @Demigan the lungs aren't _really_ automatic. That's mostly what kills you you've been affected by neurotoxins. Lightning strikes often kill people as a result of asphyxia; the heart often spontaneously restarts but breathing doesn't, etc etc. Artificial respiration will tide the victims over.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that permanently paralyzing an enemy soldier without killing isn't desirable in any military conflict.

If one side had such a weapon, it wouldn't be long before it was obtained by the other side and by terrorists who would use it on civilians. What then would become of all of these paralyzed players and victims? Would they lay in the field and die a slow torturous death? The carnage is bad enough as it is without that humanitarian disaster.

I think nanomachines will be eventually weaponized. Imagine something dust like in nature that can attach itself to the enemy, enter and temporarily block their ability to walk and/or hold a weapon by short circuiting specific parts of their nervous system. What if it just dumbed them down to where they couldn't be a threat and the effect would be easily reversable with the correct signal? There would be less carnage and plenty of prisoners for the taking. What's more, nanomachines could spread in a strategic manner from a few infected soldiers to disable an entire platoon and the allies could be immunized with a specific DNA code so as not to be affected.

Comment: While I agree with the points you are making, it is not an answer to the question "Is X possible/feasible".  This would be more appropriate as a comment on the (aged) question rather than an answer, once you have sufficient reputation to add comments.

Comment: Welcome Rob. I agree, the basis of the question needs challenging and the usual place for this is in comments. We have something called a [frame challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7097/a-proposal-for-helping-users-understand-frame-challenges) (from our meta site) which is what you seem to have composed here. Worth reading the link to polish your technique when employing this.